# how to get the UISearchController's search results table view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisearchcontroller

I defined a `UISearchController` instance like this:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

but cannot find a way to get a reference to its search results table view.
 previously using `UISearchDisplayController` it's easy as:

```
self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.reloadData()
```

p.s. I know that if I define it like:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: aTableViewControllerInstance)
```

then the search results table view will be `aTableViewControllerInstance.tableView` but in my case I didn't use a table view controller.

Comment: i think the `UISearchController ` needs `UITableViewController` to work, it just produce an array after search then u update your tableviewcontroller with it?

Comment: it's already working with UITableViewController

Answer (score 2):

When you have the following line:

```
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

This is not saying that there is no search results controller, it is saying the search results controller is the same view controller as in which it appears. Therefore the results tableView is your current view controller's tableView (ie. `self.tableView)`.

Have you set `searchResultsUpdater`? It is here you need to filter as appropriate, and so you will have the results available.

A good example of what you want to do is [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial).